# SQL query comparing decimal values not matching and returns NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, case

I have a SQL query and between the fields that it consult have a validation that compare a field called "tipo" and depending of it will assign to "dias_validez" field a value, problem is when case is a decimal number like "0.7" or "1.5", validation doesn't work and return NULL values

```
SELECT
    Usuario.`id_usuario`,
    Usuario.`nombre_usuario`,
    Usuario.`groupon`,
    Groupon.`tipo`,
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) AS dias_pasados,
    Perfil.`comoseentero`,

    CASE 
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 1 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) <=24 THEN 0
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 1 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) >24 AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) <=30 THEN 1
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 1 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) >30 THEN 2
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 2 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) <=54 THEN 0
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 2 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) >54 AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) <=54 THEN 1
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 2 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) >60 THEN 2
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 3 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) <=84 THEN 0
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 3 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) >84 AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) <=94 THEN 1
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 3 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Facturacion.`fecha_inicio`) >90 THEN 2
    END AS resultado,

    CASE
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 1 THEN 30
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 2 THEN 60
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 3 THEN 90
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 0.7 THEN 21
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 1.2 THEN 35
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 1.5 THEN 45
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 12 THEN 365
    WHEN Groupon.`tipo` = 0 THEN 'N/A'
    END AS dias_validez
    FROM
    Usuario
    JOIN Groupon
    ON Usuario.`groupon` = Groupon.`groupon`
    JOIN Facturacion
    ON Facturacion.`id_proceso` = Usuario.`id_usuario`
    JOIN Perfil
    ON Usuario.`id_usuario` = Perfil.`id_proceso_perfil` GROUP BY Usuario.id_usuario ORDER BY resultado;
```

Thank you for your comments.
Excuseme please for my English skills!
Best regards

Comment: "`= 0,7`": the decimal in SQL is a `.` not a `,`.

Comment: Instead of using **=**, you could use ranges by using **BETWEEN**. For instance, one of your when clauses might be ```WHEN Groupon.`tipo` BETWEEN 0.1 AND 1.999 THEN```

Comment: If you're using `FLOAT` then sometimes 1.0 is 0.99999999958893 which can cause a whole world of hurt. Try and use `NUMERIC` fixed place numbers.

Comment: @AlejandroVelascoSoto: You must have misunderstood me. The ones using `.` (a dot) are correct, the wrong one is the one with the `,` (a comma). So `0,7` (zero comma seven) should read `0.7` (zero dot seven).

Comment: @stickybit Hahahaha you have all reason, i fixed the comma, but still no working, it continues returning null values, the initial problem

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html ?

Comment: It looks like you could simplify your `CASE` on `tipo` to `CASE WHEN Groupon.tipo = 12 THEN 365
    WHEN Groupon.tipo = 0 THEN 'N/A'
   ELSE Groupon.tipo * 30
    END` which would likely solve your floating point equality problems.

Comment: Thank you all. the problem is solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple

```
WHEN CAST(Groupon.`tipo` AS DECIMAL(10,3)) = 0.7 THEN 21
```

Just have to cast de float number to decimal and query run well.